# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'System.Byte[]'

Tags: ms-access, syntax-error, oledbexception

Hi i was using stored procedure in SQL Server to pass parameters to the query ,
but now I'm changing my database to ms access and it's my first time to deal with.

how can i pass byte[] to sql query ?
bacause i got this error 
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'System.Byte[]'.

this is my code

```
    public static int EditWhois(object ID,object Image, object Ranswer, object Fanswer1, object Fanswer2, object Fanswer3)
    {
        int result = 0;
        String sql = "UPDATE Whois SET [Image]="+@Image+", Ranswer=" + Ranswer + ", Fanswer1=" + Fanswer1 + ",Fanswer2=" + Fanswer2 + ",Fanswer3=" + Fanswer3 + " WHERE ID=" + ID;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sql);
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID); 
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", Image);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranswer", Ranswer);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fanswer1", Fanswer1);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fanswer2", Fanswer2);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fanswer3", Fanswer3);

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you commenting out the parameterized lines? Why is every argument in your method an `object`? Which one's a `byte[]`?

Comment: Use a parametrized placeholder (it looks like this was originally attempted). It will clean up the code and get rid of the error.

Comment: i'm commenting the parametrized lines because i'm directly passing arguments to the query ,my arguments are objects to avoid casting , the byte[] is the @Image

Comment: parametrized query resulting the same error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result is still 0;
i know the problem where it was .
if the connection is closed the query will be executed successfully , but if it is opend it will not be executed due to this condition .

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    con.Open();
    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

it must be

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    con.Open();
}
    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

thanks all .

Answer (score 0):

Use @ parameter substitution.  Also as @BoltClock says, change you method signature.

```
public static int EditWhois(object ID,object Image, object Ranswer, 
    object Fanswer1, object Fanswer2, object Fanswer3)
{
    int result = 0;
    String sql = "UPDATE Whois SET [Image]=@Image, Ranswer=@Ranswer, " + 
      "Fanswer1=@Fanswer1, Fanswer2=@Fanswer2, Fanswer3=@Fanswer3 " +
      "WHERE ID=@ID";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", Image);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ranswer", Ranswer);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fanswer1", Fanswer1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fanswer2", Fanswer2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fanswer3", Fanswer3);

    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Open();
        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```